# Failed to create a shortcut with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, shortcut, network-drive

I would like to create a shortcut of a PowerShell script in SendTo folder with PowerShell.
My script is like below and worked on my laptop, but failed on a PC at workplace.

A possible difference between those two environment is that both the script and SendTo folder are located in a local drive on my laptop while they are on a network drive at office.

```
# Create a WScript object
$WsShell=New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell

# Create a shortcut
$SendToDirectory=Join-Path $env:APPDATA "\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\test.lnk"
$Shortcut=$WsShell.CreateShortcut("$SendToDirectory")

# Set PowerShell location as a target path
$PowerShellFullPath=cmd /c where powershell
$Shortcut.TargetPath=$PowerShellFullPath

# Set arguments to pass to the power shell
$Shortcut.Arguments="-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`""

# Shortcut configuration
$PowerShellPath=[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($PowerShellFullPath)
$Shortcut.WorkingDirectory=$PowerShellPath
$Shortcut.WindowStyle=1 # 1:Normal/2:Max/7:Min

# Save shortcut
$Shortcut.Save()
```

When I failed to create a shortcut on a office PC, no error came up, so I have no idea what is wrong.
For debugging I ran the below script on PowerShell ISE Console,

```
$WsShell=New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$SendToDirectory=".test.lnk"
$Shortcut=$WsShell.CreateShortcut("$SendToDirectory")
```

and then

```
$Shortcut
```

The result was like this (I am replacing the path to ***)

```
FullName         : ***\test.lnk
Arguments        : 
Description      : 
Hotkey           : 
IconLocation     : ,0
RelativePath     : 
TargetPath       : 
WindowStyle      : 1
WorkingDirectory :
```

This indicates that the object is properly created but does not appear on the network drive as intended.

I would appreciate it if anyone give me a tip to settle this out.

**<Addition on 2 Oct 2020>**
The code runs without an error, but on the folder a shortcut never appears. Also, at the end of the script I added test-path to test the shortcut existence and it showed that the shortcut does not exist. That's why I said "failed to create a shortcut".

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine. Which Powershell version are you using?

Comment: How did you determine that it failed?

Comment: possibly this .lnk file already exitst and it's hidden. CreateShortcut actually opens shortcut file without errors if it exists already ( and you can read it's properties ). Try replacing `test.lnk` with `some random letters.lnk`

Comment: Are you using Roaming profiles or redirected folders ?

Comment: @filimonic  I tried some random names but the result was the same. I am not sure if I am using Roaming profiles or redirected folders. How can I find it?

Comment: Explain your phrase `while they are on a network drive at office` detailed. Ask your IT Dept for help.